# Is "put in by hand" a correct expression?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> In the present theory, these things are assumptions we have to **put in by hand**.
>
> — *[Physics from Symmetry](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bipBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false),* Jakob Schwichtenberg, Springer International Publishing 2015

I can roughly understand it means "we have to take these assumptions for granted", but not sure whether **put in by hand** is a standard expression or not.

Comment: No; one _makes_ assumptions. 'These are at the moment necessary hypotheses, nothing more.'

Comment: "Put in by hand" is fine. It might be said of plants or emendations to a text. Putting assumptions into a theory "by hand" is perhaps unusual.

Comment: I would interpret it to mean just based on judgement of a guess, vs having some scientific/mathematical underpinnings.

Comment: What @Andrew said. Actually, I don't think this is a very sensible use of idiomatic "put in by hand", because ordinarily to ***make assumptions*** and to ***put [values] in by hand** [into an equation or theory]* effectively mean the same thing - so it amounts to saying ***We have to assume assumptions***. In support of which I note that the specific instance cited here is the ***only*** occurrence of the sequence "**assumptions we have to put in by hand**" returned by a google search (and there are none at all for "**assumptions we put in by hand**").

Comment: **Put in by hand** does not mean *take for granted*. In fact, those two things have nothing to do with each other. Further, *take for granted* isn't suggested anywhere in that sentences. A rephrasing would be *… these things are assumptions we have to **manually introduce**.*

Comment: Thank you for your answers!!